# Creat a listview in cide behind with List<list<string>> as a source and grid as data template

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, grid

Structure.Values is List<list>

in code behind I set listviewdata template

```
var grid = new grid();
grid.columnspacing = 0;
grid.rowspacing = 0;
grid.backgroundcolor = color.black;
grid.columndefinitions = new columndefinitioncollection();
grid.rowdefinitions = new rowdefinitioncollection();
grid = creategridrowscolumns(datalist, grid);
var tapgesturerecognizer = new tapgesturerecognizer();
tapgesturerecognizer.setbinding(tapgesturerecognizer.commandproperty, new binding("bindingcontext.detailscommand", source: listviewm));
tapgesturerecognizer.setbinding(tapgesturerecognizer.commandparameterproperty, ".");
grid.gesturerecognizers.add(tapgesturerecognizer);
```

and the data to set the grid data as

```
    private Grid CreateGridRowsColumns(IEnumerable list, Grid grid)
    {
        var lst = list as List<List<string>>;
        int row = 0;
        foreach (var ro in lst)
        {
            int column = 0;
            foreach (var col in ro)
            {
                Label title = new Label
                {
                    Text = col,
                    Style = GetResourceValue("DataLabelStyle") as Style
                };
                grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
                grid.Children.Add(title, column,row);
                column++;
            }
            row++;
        }
        return grid;
    }
```

so how to use listview to produce the same effect

Edit:

My ViewModel

```
public class BaseListViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ExcelStructure Structure { get; private set; }
}
```

and Model :

```
public class ExcelStructure
{
    public List<string> Headers { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public List<List<string>> Values { get; set; } = new List<List<string>>();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want. Do you want to have a number of columns in each Item? Each item in the ListView is equivalent to a row in the Grid, and then there are several columns in a row, right?

If yes,you could try below:

```
 public ListGridPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BaseListViewModel  listModel = new BaseListViewModel();
        BindingContext = listModel;
        listViewm.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {
     
            return new MyViewCell();
        });
       
    }

  class MyViewCell : ViewCell
    {
        protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
        {
            base.OnBindingContextChanged();
            List<string> structure = (List<string>)BindingContext;
            var grid = new Grid();
            grid.ColumnSpacing = 0;
            grid.RowSpacing = 0;
            grid.ColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionCollection();
            grid.RowDefinitions = new RowDefinitionCollection();
            grid = Creategridrowscolumns(structure, grid);
            this.View = grid;
        }
        private Grid Creategridrowscolumns(List<string> structure, Grid grid)
        {
            var lst = structure as List<string>;

            int column = 0;
            foreach (var col in structure)
            {
                Label title = new Label
                {
                    Text = col,
                };
                grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(200, GridUnitType.Star) });
                grid.Children.Add(title, column, 0);
                column++;
            }

            return grid;
        }

    }
```

viewmodel:

```
class BaseListViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ExcelStructure Structure { get; private set; }
    public BaseListViewModel()
    {
        Structure = new ExcelStructure();
    }
}
```

model:

```
 public class ExcelStructure
 {

    public List<List<string>> Values { get; set; }

    public ExcelStructure()
    {
        Values = new List<List<string>>();
        Values.Add(new List<string>() {"1-A", "1-B", "1-C", "1-D", "1-E" });
        Values.Add(new List<string>() { "2-A", "2-B", "2-C", "2-D", "2-E" });
        Values.Add(new List<string>() { "3-A", "3-B", "3-C", "3-D", "3-E" });
        Values.Add(new List<string>() { "4-A", "4-B", "4-C", "4-D", "4-E" });
    }
}
```

the effect like:

[image]

Comment: I edited the post, the code result is (x, y) grid list, but how to use the same effect using listview. I tried your code the binding context is viewModel which has property List<List<string>> not List<string>

Comment: @SherifAwad Could you share your viewmodel codes? Or i show my viewmodel,you could refer to it and change.

Comment: @ Leo Zhu - MSFT  I added my viewmodel, so the listview itemsource Structure.Values

Comment: @SherifAwad You could try to check the above codes again.If this effect you want ?